# Postgresql date_trunc called in custom function through Django's connection.cursor()

Tags: django, postgresql, django-database, django-postgresql, django-timezone

I created a custom Postgresql function that performs some calculations and determines the beginning of a month by using the `date_trunc` function. When developing the custom function, I checked it from within a database connection established with psql which worked just fine. Though such a connection I get the following output:

```
select date_trunc('month', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-09-14 04:10:00+02');
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2014-09-01 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Which is exactly what I want: It gives me the beginning of the month at my timezone.
If I try to do the same from within a django shell (I am using the psycopg2 connector), I get a different result:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("select date_trunc('month', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-09-14 04:10:00+02');")
>>> unicode(cursor.fetchone()[0])
u'2014-09-01 00:00:00+00:00'
```

As you can see, the database returns the beginning of the month at UTC, resulting in a two hour offset to the actual timestamp I wanted to have.

This is a result of django setting the database connection's timestamp to UTC which results in `date_trunc` truncating the month at UTC time.
I tried setting the timezone of the connection manually by using `SET TIMEZONE TO 'Europe/Berlin'`, but this results in an `AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")`.

The following workaround does work in my case but it is not really a pretty solution. It only works since I do not need any return values from my function.

```
cursor.execute("SET TIMEZONE to 'Europe/Berlin'; my_function(parameters); SET TIMEZONE to 'UTC';")
```

I am hoping that somebody can help me figure out a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use AT TIME ZONE 'FOO' or TIMEZONE('FOO', timestamp) in the query (using a parameter for the actual time zone name as appropriate); see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT
2. Create a context manager for the query that saves/sets/restores the time zone around the particular query